# Printing group name of data frame in R

Tags: r

So I have a data frame in which I have three columns and data like this (I have more groups than this):

```
group    x    y
group_1  5    1
group_1  6    2
group_1  7    3
group_2  8    4
group_2  9    5
group_2  10   6
group_2  11   7
```

I now wish to do something with it obviously, so I can use different command to target only `group_2` `x`-values and so forth.

However, I'm trying to do some loop stuff, and would like it to say, in the output, that I'm am now using `group_1` or `group_2`. But I am kind of lost in how to do this.

So for example I have this simple code (I know I could target the columns instant, but this is just a bit easier now):

```
data_group_1 <- subset(data, group =="group_1")
data_group_2 <- subset(data, group =="group_2")

data_grouped <- list(data_group_1$x, data_group_2$x)

for (data_group in data_grouped) {
    print(mean(data_group))
}
```

Now, as stated, I would like it to print the name of the group before printing the mean value of the `x`-values, so I know which mean belongs to what (I could have 100 groups in principle). But I am unsure how to target the group name just once, and use it as a name/string. So any hints or help to do this ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using subset for this is fairly bad. The reason is that it's not scalable to many groups - lots of copypasting - and if you don't know in advance how many groups there are, it's extremely tricky.

It's much easier to use the page `dplyr`, which lets you group your dataframe and then do groupwise operations:

```r
library(dplyr)
data_example <- data.frame(
  group = c(rep("group_1", 3), rep("group_2", 4)),
  x = 5:11,
  y = 1:7
)
data_example %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(max_x = max(x))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>     group max_x
#>    <fctr> <dbl>
#> 1 group_1     7
#> 2 group_2    11
```

This eliminates the need to loop, and the need to show which group you're currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data is loaded in the dataframe d. Then,

> aggregate(d[, 2:3], list(d$group), mean)

should give you the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

another simple approach

```
data_group_1 <- subset(data$x, group =="group_1")
data_group_2 <- subset(data$x, group =="group_2")

data_grouped <- data.frame()
data_grouped <- cbind.data.frame(data_group_1, data_group_2)

for (i in 1:ncol(data_grouped) ) {

  print(names(data_grouped)[i])

  print(mean(data_grouped[,i]))

}
```